# Overlap Deluxe!

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, poetry, affix-riddle

My prefix used to levitate a ball
When he was just a lowly youth, and small.
His friends are not con, but surely quite pro.
He's rarely an object, just so you know.

My infix will happily take your place,
And sounds like something that is on your face.
Of terrible storms, she's sometimes a part,
Yet always has your best interest at heart.

My suffix shrinks you way down to just one,
And can be dodgy if left with the sun.
While comfy with friends, she can stand alone.
She is your friend, but she's not in your phone.

What word am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess, but is the word

> **I**?

Because

> *My prefix used to levitate a ball
>
>  When he was just a lowly youth, and small.*
>
> A lowercase "i" appears to have a ball hovering above it.
>
> *His friends are not con, but surely quite pro.*
>
> I is a **pro**noun
>  Also, "Aye" is used to indicate agreement - pro and not con.
>
> *He's rarely an object, just so you know.*
>
> "I" is typically the subject of a sentence, not the object.
>
> *My infix will happily take your place,*
>
> "I" is a word you use to refer to yourself.
>
> *And sounds like something that is on your face.*
>
> "I" sounds like "eye."
>
> *Of terrible storms, she's sometimes a part,*
>
> The "eye" of the storm.
>
> *Yet always has your best interest at heart.*
>
> "I" always have my own best interests at heart. (Or is this a play on the letter I being used to represent interest in financial mathematics?)
>
> *My suffix shrinks you way down to just one,*
>
> "I" is the Roman numeral for one.
>  Also, no matter how many letters are in your name, using the word I in place of your name shrinks the number of letters needed down to just one.
>
> *And can be dodgy if left with the sun.*
>
> Your "eye" evades the sun's brightness with hats or sunglasses.
>
> *While comfy with friends, she can stand alone.*
>
> "I" is found in many words, but can also stand alone as its own word.
>
> *She is your friend, but she's not in your phone.*
>
> You typically don't have yourself as a contact in your phone?
>
> And the title hints that since the word is only a single character, the prefix, infix and suffix all overlap - they are all just the letter I.

Comment: You're on fire, SQLnoob! Spot on with all but a few of those. Watch out, Puzzling, there's a new Stiv in town!

Comment: Filled in a few things. I hope you don't mind. Also, it never occurred to me in the context of this puzzle that rot13: (V vf gur Ebzna ahzreny 1!)    Geesh. Good find